# change Log on (user) for IIS Admin service - Error 1068 The dependency service or group failed to start

Tags: iis, admin

I am tasked to change the user for IIS Admin, WWW publishing service, and HTTP SSL windows services for IIS6 (Windows 2003). 
It works perfectly with Local System account (by default the selection with this fresh instance of Windows 2003) - but I have to change the user - not negotiable for me unfortunately as it is a must do instruction from my boss to me.

The user Im trying to set it to e.g. UserABC is on the Server and is the Log On for other services which execute without problems.

So first I tried setting the Log On for HTTP SSL but received the error:
"Error 1079 : the account specified for this service is different from the account specified for other services running in the same process".
Now when I looked at the dependencies I saw that WWW publishing service is dependent on HTTP SSL.

So I tried setting the Log on for WWW publishing service, but got the error:
"Could not start the WWW Publishing service on local computer"
"Error 5: Access is denied"

Now I tried setting the user for IIS admin, but received the error:
"Could not start the IIS admin service on local computer: Error 1068 : The dependency service or group failed to start"

Any advice please on how I can change the user log on for these services? The instance of IIS is working fine and its just the password that I need to set. Are there folders which I have to assign rights to for UserABC perhaps? Something else I'm missing?

The other forums on the web suggest things like deleting "MetaBase.bin", or running MS fix: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827328 but this will not work for me on this new server - but I do not want to muck around with this please.

Thank you